# apparmor profile creation for ruby script

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apparmor

i am trying to create apparmor profile for ruby file named test.rb and put that file under /root, test.rb contain:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
`mkdir demo`
```

i created apparmor profile by following way:

```
aa-genprof test.rb
```

above command successfully created apparmor profile for that test.rb, Now i wants that this test.rb file should not create anything inside /root directory except read access. So i made following changes in apparmor profile for test.rb file:

```
 Last Modified: Mon Sep 29 06:59:34 2014
#include <tunables/global>

/root/test.rb {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  /root/test.rb mr,
  /root/ r,
}
```

Now i restart and reloaded apparmor by following way:

```
sudo service apparmor restart
```

so i assumed that when i will run my test.rb should not create any directory inside /root directory, But when i run this file like this way:

```
ruby test.rb
```

Its create demo directory inside /root

```
ls /root
demo
```

I dont understand why this produce this behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

When you ran the program via `ruby test.rb`, AppArmor did not attach the profile to the process. You ran `/usr/bin/ruby`, not `/root/test.rb`.

The fix is simple enough:

```
chmod 755 /root/test.rb
/root/test.rb
```

Thanks